# old ibm trackpoint pin scheme

Tags: pinout, teensy

I have a trackpoint from a thinkpad keyboard with a trackpoint mounting a PTPM754DR microcontroller, what I'm trying to do is to find the usage of various pin on the trackpoint board and connect them to a teensy 2.0 that already controls a keyboard (I'm using this firmware https://github.com/tmk/tmk_keyboard), what I've found on various sites and forums like geekhack are info from other trackpoints with a different pinout, I say so because I've traced at least the mouse buttons and saw the vcc and ground that have bigger traces than the others, how can I find the purpose of other pins? I cannot connect that keyboard back to a laptop.

[Here is some images of the trackpoint and what I was able, probably, to trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhoLJ.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=8971.msg775152#msg775152) on the geekhack forum:

> R61 trackpoint pinout (with PTPM754DR) « Reply #20 on: Wed, 23 January 2013, 08:04:09 »
>
> 1. DATA
> 2. RST
> 3. BTN1
> 4. BTN2
> 5. BTN3
> 6. CLOCK
> 7. GND
> 8. VCC
>
> When connecting to PS/2 interface, DATA and CLK should be pulled up to vcc using 4k7 resistor, RST to GND using 100k resistor and RST to vcc using 2.2uF capacitor.
>
> [image]

Notice the boards look identical. Also [this other post](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=55960.msg1269252#msg1269252) and [another](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=55960.msg1291412#msg1291412):

> [image]

That last post has **everything** you need for using your trackpoint on the TMK firmware too.

Comment: I saw both of those posts but does this mean I got my tracing wrong? (notice the mouse pinout I was able to trace with a tester) I don't want to fry the teensy by connecting wrong pins, is there a precaution I can take in this regard?

Comment: @araif your traced mouse buttons match theirs. 3rd, 4th, 5th traces, starting from the bottom. Your board has a trace that looks empty, ignore that one, and start counting from the first trace the cable is wired to.

Comment: yes but I have btn2 and btn1 inverted, I tested that different time and I'm pretty sure is not a mistake, but I'll retry later this evening.

Comment: @araif the buttons are arbitrary. A switch is a switch, doesn't matter if you call it btn1 or btn2.

Comment: yes but given that difference I was wondering if also other pins were different, leading me to damage some component.

Comment: @araif these boards are so similar, there is no reason to expect that. And even then, these are all outputs except for clk. And ps/2 is an open drain protocol. The pull up resistor does the work. You'll be fine.