# Determining TrackPoint pinout

Tags: pinout

I have salvaged this TrackPoint from a lenovo laptop keyboard. Unfortunately I don't know the exact model, but I don't think it's older than say 6 years. I would like to connect this to my PC via an Arduino, mbed, teensy or direct PS/2 and use it as a mouse.

**Here's my question**: What's the pinout of this device, or how can I find out what it is (without harming the device)?

I've found numerous pinouts online, but none of the pictures/descriptions that have pinouts appear to match the PDB layout of my TrackPoint, because they typically have the VCC and GND rails close together, whereas mine appear to be on pins 1 & 5, since those lines are the thickest in the flexible connector. Furthermore, my TrackPoint has 8 pins, many of the ones found around the web have 10. I don't have the keyboard or laptop anymore, so I can't exactly use a multimeter to measure voltages in a working system.

Here are some pictures, I'll add links to the sources I've found so far below.

[image: TrackPoint front]

[image: TrackPoint back]

### Markings:

PCB front:

- LVC9
- 142399H
- Rev. A

PCB back:

- 1046
- CPCP GG
- 94V-O
- C 9U

The bigger chip (32 pins):

- PTPM754DR
- CT2926 10
- D104IC
- 0 B

What I've found so far..

- [This question on this site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/155662/86171): VCC & GND are on adjacent pins
- [TrackPoint @ deskthority](http://deskthority.net/wiki/TrackPoint) - has some good links to firmwares and datasheets for the controller
- [Pinout for 10 pin TrackPoint](https://github.com/frobiac/adnw/blob/master/README.pinout)
- [This question on geekhack.org](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=8971.0) seems to be about a similar (maybe even the same) TrackPoint, but the owner at some point gave up and went back to a TrackPoint powered by a 28-pin controller.
- [This keyboard hack](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=11420.0) seems to use a TrackPoint which looks exactly the same, but I think he's using the keyboard controller to interface with the TrackPoint.
- [More trackpoint pinouts](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=55960.msg1291412#msg1291412)
- [USB trackpoint library on GitHub](https://github.com/feklee/usb-trackpoint) (10 pin trackpoint)

Any ideas?

Comment: This Chip has a datasheet, TPM754 - [link](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dlmain/Datasheets-112/DSAP0046162.pdf) its a phillips IC that has IBM licensed embedded TrackPoint microcode . It even has a convenient suggested application schematic and pinout, WOW!

Comment: Note that's for the TPM754DB, not DR. The TPM754DB has 28 rather than 32 pins.

Comment: I'm also on the similar quest to find pinout of different trackpoint module. If you have any info, share with me here:
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/562258/how-to-detect-pinout-of-trackpoint-probably-ps-2-module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to completely reverse the pins of this module:

Considering your first picture above, being the rightmost pin the number 1 (near the white dot), I've got, from right to left:

1. Mousebutton0
2. Mousebutton1
3. Mousebutton2
4. 5V
5. Reset
6. Clock
7. Data
8. Ground

**Update:** I confirm it works finally as described above. I'm using tmk firmware and tried on teensy2.0 and pro micro.

Comment: How did you manage to reverse it, if I may ask? I stand woth the same question, but a different module.