# How to detect pinout of trackpoint (probably ps/2) module?

Tags: pinout, laptop, keyboard, ps2, joystick

I have following trackpoint module of recent thinkpad x390.
There are some info about older modules, most useful(combined) one is: https://deskthority.net/wiki/TrackPoint_Hardware

However, i found no info about this trackpoint module (which seems  most of newer thinkpads use).

- IC has label "33306B 3900 1851 BG18CK2" (no datasheet on internet)
- On the backside: pcb has label "PSG8E8-Rev.2 AD19021218" (no results on google)

Current findings:

- I'm only guessing 2nd pin of 8pin FPC connector is the GND. I have no idea what are the others.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep, there are nothing ic/electronics related result when "bg18ck2" is searched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to know as well so i hooked up a logic analyzer to it installed in a thinkpad.
it's not tested yet, so maybe be a bit careful but my measurements say that, from left to right:

pin 0:clock
pin 1:GND
pin 2:mouse1
pin 3:mouse2
pin 4:mouse3
pin 5:reset
pin 6:data
pin 7:VCC

Comment: OH yeah, I couple of weeks ago, I did with Logic analyzer too. 
Appreciate for answering for that, I forgot to comment my findings.